# Share code dependencies between micro services in nodejs

Tags: node.js, microservices

I'm designing a platform that use 3 micro services; a *socket server*, a *front end server* running expressjs and a *email server* to send transaccional emails.

The project file strutture is very simple:

```
project_root
 |______________ socket
 |______________ frontend
 |______________ email
```

Inside each folder there is a nodejs project. To comunicate with each other these micro services use a simple [Redis pub/sub implementation](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). The thing is, inside each *node_modules* folder there is going to be an NPM package duplicate for the Redis dependency. So there is duplicated code and if I want update the package I'll have to do it 3 times.

Am I using an incorrect approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started a NodeJS project with a similar structure and it quickly became a mess.  I moved node_modules, common code, and package.json to the project root and used separate startup files so that I could share common code between the projects.  It turned out much easier to deploy and maintain.

```
root
|_ socket
|_ frontend
|_ email
|_ node_modules
|_ package.json
|_ app_socket.js
|_ app_frontend.js
|_ app_email.js
```